# Bi-directional communication to thermal printer by windows drivers

Tags: c#, windows, printing, spooler

I need to develop an application to print to thermal printers such as Epson ESC/POS protocol or ZPL Zebra protocol.
I can write raw code to printer using network printers, serial port printers and also window's spooler printers.
My trouble starts when I need to "query" the prnter to get its status (ready, error, paper end and so on), in this case I need a reverse communication, I send a special command and the printer answer with some status bytes.
With network/socket printers or serial port printers everything is clear... with windows printers I can not understand how to read the printers status...

Is there any solution?

**UPDATE**

Following Hans's suggestion I'm trying to read the printer using Windows API. This is my test with ESC/POS protocol.

```
public class WinPrinter
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ReadPrinter", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ReadPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwNReadBytes); 

    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            string reaDstrinG = "";
            Int32 buf = 0;
            Int32 pcRead;
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            bool read = ReadPrinter(hPrinter, sb.Append(reaDstrinG), buf, out pcRead);
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;


      }

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String test = "\u0010\u0004\u0001";
            IntPtr pBytes=Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(test);
            Int32 dwCount = test.Length;
            WinPrinter.SendBytesToPrinter("BIXOLON SRP-350 (Copia 1)",pBytes,dwCount);
        }

    }
```

I'm sure that "\u0010\u0004\u0001" (DLE EOT 1) is the commend to request printer status in ESCPOS protocol, I tested it with the same printer connected by serial and I got a status byte.

However with the code above I alway get false from ReadPrinter method.
I checked that the printer port has "bidirectional" option enabled and I also tried without the spooler option.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I added a little update because with ReadPrinter method I got nothing

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only solution I have found is to use the specific SDK from printer manufacturer, for example Zebra provides a library to discover and communicate with the printer. But this is not a universal method, it works only with Zebra printers.